# Getting access to constructor variable in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How I can get access and work on variable from constructor?

When I initialize my function hello I get error:

> Message: Undefined variable: type2

Library:

```
class MyLibrary {


public function __construct($params)
{
    echo $params['type'];

    //I WANT TO DISPLAY TYPE2 BY HELLO FUNCTION
    $type2 = 'asdasdasd';
}

public function hello(){

    return $type2;
}
}
```

My controller:

```
  public function test()
{
    $params = array('type' => 'large', 'color' => 'red');
    $this->load->library('TwitterAPI', $params);

     //I WANT TO DISPLAY $TYPE2 
     echo $this->twitterapi->hello();

}
```

Comment: $this->type2 should do it with inherited methods, so **public function  hello(){ return $this->type2; }**

Comment: @DanWhite Im getting error: `Undefined property: MyLibrary:$type2`

Comment: Comment out / remove the echo... in the constructor. Furthermore, have you initiated the library? $this->load->library('mylibrary')

Comment: That echo have nothing to do with my variable $type2, and that echo works fine. Type2 of course still doesn't work with commented echo $params

Comment: ***Furthermore, have you initiated the library? $this->load->library('mylibrary') *** This goes in your controller, or if you need to, autoload it in the config dir

Comment: @DanWhite Yep, I did this. Library is working fine, `echo $params['type'];` is displayed in my view by controller but that `$type2`...

Comment: @Steve answered before I finished my comment. **private $type2;**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a private member variable:

```
class MyLibrary {

    private $type2;

    public function __construct($params)
    {
        echo $params['type'];

        //I WANT TO DISPLAY TYPE2 BY HELLO FUNCTION
        $this->type2 = 'asdasdasd';
    }

    public function hello()
    {

        return $this->type2;
    }

}
```